# control of title parameters of a plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I was trying to set a single common title, and a unique common x-y-axis labels for 4 combined subplots:

```
dev.new( width =  9, height = 10)
layout( matrix( c( 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 0, 7, 7 ), 4, 3, byrow = TRUE), widths = c( 1, 4, 4 ), heights = c( 1, 4, 4, 1 ) )
par( mar = c( 1, 0, 1, 0 ) )
plot( c(1:2), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F, cex = 0.7 ) #general title 
title( main = "title", ps = 2 )
par( mar = c( 1, 0, 1, 1) )
plot( c(1:2), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F, las = 2, cex = 0.7 ) #general y-label  
title( main = " y-label ", las = 0 )
par( cex= 0.9,  mar = c( 5, 1, 1, 2 ) )
plot( c(1:10), type="l", xlab = "A", ylab = "", axes = T, las = 1, cex = 0.7 ) # first    subplot 
par( cex= 0.9,  mar = c( 5, 1, 1, 3 ) )
plot( c(10:1), type ="l", xlab = "B", ylab = "", axes = T, las = 1, cex = 0.7 ) # second subplot
par( cex= 0.9,  mar = c( 5, 1, 1, 2 ) )
plot( c(1:10), type="l", xlab = "C", ylab = "", axes = T, las = 1, cex = 0.7 ) # third subplot
par( cex= 0.9,  mar = c( 5, 1, 1, 3 ) )
plot( c(1:2), type="l", xlab = "D", ylab = "", axes = T, las = 1, cex = 0.7 ) # fourth subplot
par(mar = c( 1, 0, 1, 0 ) )
plot( c(1:2), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = F, cex = 0.7 ) #general x-label
title( main = " x-label " )
```

How can I control for font size, position and orientation of these titles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is a an outer margin for the entire figure. Set it with `par(oma=...)` and add the axis labels and title in it with `mtext(..., outer=TRUE)`.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), oma=c(3,3,4,0), mar=c(4,2,1,1), las=1, cex=0.7)
plot(1:10, type="l", xlab="A", ylab="")
plot(10:1, type ="l", xlab="B", ylab="")
plot(1:10, type="l", xlab="C", ylab="")
plot(1:2, type="l", xlab="D", ylab="")
mtext("X-label", 1, 1, outer=TRUE)
mtext("Y-label", 2, 1, outer=TRUE, las=0)
mtext("Title", 3, 1, outer=TRUE, cex=2)
```

[image]

Note that `1:10` is equivalent to `c(1:10)` and that all `par` settings that are constant across panels A-D only need to be set once, in the `par` call.

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved in a very coarse way using the xlab and ylab parameters of null plots placed in the corresponding site of the layout

Comment: I used to do that too until last week when a new girl at the office stumbled upon `oma`. Mind blown.